# F# async stack overflow

Tags: asynchronous, f#, mapreduce

I am surprised by a stack overflow in my async-based program. I suspect the main problem is with the following function, which is supposed to compose two async computations to execute in parallel and wait for both to finish:

```
let ( <|> ) (a: Async<unit>) (b: Async<unit>) =
    async {
        let! x = Async.StartChild a
        let! y = Async.StartChild b
        do! x
        do! y
    }
```

With this defined, I have the following `mapReduce` program that attempts to exploit parallelism in both the `map` and the `reduce` part. Informally, the idea is to spark `N` mappers and `N-1` reducers using a shared channel, wait for them to finish, and read the result from the channel. I had my own `Channel` implementation, here replaced by a `ConcurrentBag` for shorter code (the problem affects both):

```
let mapReduce (map    : 'T1 -> Async<'T2>)
              (reduce : 'T2 -> 'T2 -> Async<'T2>)
              (input  : seq<'T1>) : Async<'T2> =
    let bag = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag()

    let rec read () =
        async {
            match bag.TryTake() with
            | true, value -> return value
            | _           -> do! Async.Sleep 100
                             return! read ()
        }

    let write x =
        bag.Add x
        async.Return ()

    let reducer =
        async {
            let! x = read ()
            let! y = read ()
            let! r = reduce x y
            return bag.Add r
        }

    let work =
        input
        |> Seq.map (fun x -> async.Bind(map x, write))
        |> Seq.reduce (fun m1 m2 -> m1 <|> m2 <|> reducer)

    async {
        do! work
        return! read ()
    }
```

Now the following basic test starts to throw StackOverflowException on n=10000:

```
let test n  =
    let map x      = async.Return x
    let reduce x y = async.Return (x + y)
    mapReduce map reduce [0..n]
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

EDIT: An alternative implementation of the `<|>` combinator makes the test succeed on N=10000:

```
let ( <|> ) (a: Async<unit>) (b: Async<unit>) =
  Async.FromContinuations(fun (ok, _, _) ->
    let count = ref 0
    let ok () =
        lock count (fun () ->
            match !count with
            | 0 -> incr count
            | _ -> ok ())
    Async.Start <|
        async {
            do! a
            return ok ()
        }
    Async.Start <|
        async {
            do! b
            return ok ()
        })
```

This is really surprising to me because this is what I assumed `Async.StartChild` is doing. Any thoughts on which solution would be optimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the stack overflow exception happens when starting the asynchronous workflow created using the `<|>` operator. The call to `Async.StartChild` starts the first workflow, which is combined using `<|>` and so it makes another call to `Async.StartChild` etc.

An easy way to fix it is to schedule the workflow in a handler of a timer (so that the it isn't added to the current stack). Something like:

```
let ( <|> ) (a: Async<unit>) (b: Async<unit>) =
    async {
        do! Async.Sleep 1
        let! x = Async.StartChild a
        let! y = Async.StartChild b
        do! x
        do! y }
```

A better way to fix it would be to create your own `Seq.reduce` - the current implementation folds it one-by-one so you'll get a tree of depth 10000, that contains just a single work item on the right, and all other work items on the left. If you created a ballanced binary tree of work items, then it shouldn't stackoverflow because the height will be only 15 or so.

**EDIT** Try replacing `Seq.reduce` with the following function:

```
module Seq = 
  let reduceBallanced f input =
    let arr = input |> Array.ofSeq
    let rec reduce s t =
      if s + 1 >= t then arr.[s]
      else 
        let m = (s + t) / 2
        f (reduce s m) (reduce m t)
    reduce 0 arr.Length
```

Comment: Using `Async.Sleep 1` makes the code much slower. Although that probably wouldn't be as visible when the `map` and `reduce` functions actually did some useful work, that takes some time.

Comment: Actually, i don't care about time/space complexity right now - I am just really surprised that the code uses the stack! If the structure was on the heap this would be fine for n=10K.

Comment: @toyvo - Well, the stack overflow happens while starting the workflows, which obviously uses stack. Running the workflow doesn't need stack. The `Sleep 1` workaround was just to demonstrate that this really is the problem - using `Seq.reduce` that builds a ballanced binary tree should solve the problem without adding overhead.

Comment: I disagree, the use of stack is completely not obvious to one who is not aware of implementation details of Async. A different implementation of Async might have taken the computation off the stack, such as scheduling it on the thread pool, which was my naive expectation. Also, while your `reduceBalanced` fixes stack use it does not at all address the problem - extra sequential dependency (see below).

Comment: @toyvo - Sorry, "obviously" really wasn't a good word - I think it is understandable behavior, but I agree it isn't necessary (if you ignore implementation details). The extra sequential dependency is another issue - I think you could start all work items using `Async.StartChild` and then compose the created workflows using something like `<|>` (so you'd have two phases - one that starts all work, the other that waits for all completions).

Answer (score 2):

I believe Tomas got the intuition right in the answer, but here it is in my own words and more detail, after spending quite a bit of time to figure this out.

1. The problem is that the above code does not implement the intended `mapReduce` algorithm due to excessive synchronization. In particular, `a <|> b <|> c` does not start `c` before both `a` and `b` have completed, so in fact `<|>` is useless for parallelism with more than two computations.
2. The second problem is that `async.Return x` is isomorphic to `Async.FromContinuations(fun (ok, _, _) -> ok x)`. The example then in fact executed sequentially, on the single thread, and the allocated closures blew the stack.

For the curious reader, below is my second attempt to design this algorithm, which seems to fare a little better (~1 sec on `n=100000` and ~21 sec on `n=100000` with map and reduce functions extended with `Async.Sleep 1000`, I have Core i3).

```
let mapReduce (map    : 'T1 -> Async<'T2>)
              (reduce : 'T2 -> 'T2 -> Async<'T2>)
              (input  : seq<'T1>) : Async<'T2> =
    let run (a: Async<'T>) (k: 'T -> unit) =
        Async.StartWithContinuations(a, k, ignore, ignore)
    Async.FromContinuations <| fun (ok, _, _) ->
        let k = ref 0
        let agent =
            new MailboxProcessor<_>(fun chan ->
                async {
                    for i in 2 .. k.Value do
                        let! x = chan.Receive()
                        let! y = chan.Receive()
                        return run (reduce x y) chan.Post
                    let! r = chan.Receive()
                    return ok r
                })
        k :=
            (0, input)
            ||> Seq.fold (fun count x ->
                run (map x) agent.Post
                count + 1)
        agent.Start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting discussion!
I had a similar issue with Async.Parallel

```
let (<||>) first second = async { let! results = Async.Parallel([|first; second|]) in return   (results.[0], results.[1]) } 

let test = async { do! Async.Sleep 100 } 
(test, [1..10000]) 
||> List.fold (fun state value -> (test <||> state) |> Async.Ignore) 
|> Async.RunSynchronously // stackoverflow
```

I was very frustrated... so I solved it by creating my own Parallel combinator.

```
let parallel<'T>(computations : Async<'T> []) : Async<'T []> =
  Async.FromContinuations (fun (cont, exnCont, _) ->
    let count = ref computations.Length
    let results : 'T [] = Array.zeroCreate computations.Length
    computations 
        |> Array.iteri (fun i computation ->
            Async.Start <|
                async { 
                    try
                        let! res = computation
                        results.[i] <- res 
                    with ex -> exnCont ex

                    let n = System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(count)
                    if n = 0 then 
                        results |> cont 
                }))
```

And finally inspired by the discussion, I implemented the following mapReduce function

```
// (|f ,⊗|)

let mapReduce (mapF : 'T -> Async<'R>) (reduceF : 'R -> 'R -> Async<'R>) (input : 'T []) : Async<'R> = 
let rec mapReduce' s e =
    async { 
        if s + 1 >= e then return! mapF input.[s]
        else 
            let m = (s + e) / 2
            let! (left, right) =  mapReduce' s m <||> mapReduce' m e
            return! reduceF left right
    }
mapReduce' 0 input.Length
```

Comment: Great! I like this a lot. I wonder if Tomas had this solution in mind in his comment. I think the difference between this and my own answer is that you are using a rigid reduction scheme, while I am using first-come-first-serve. I would imagine that for some inputs my solution would come up with a better reduction order, but for most inputs would be slower because of coordination overhead. I can play the devil's advocate and construct input where my solution wins (use many fast maps, one very slow map, and slow reduce): https://gist.github.com/1131917

Comment: One important idea is that algebraically my solution requires that the reduction function must obey the associative law. (check out list homomorphism)

Comment: Sure, my solution also requires reduce to be associative. Yet you do not fully exploit the freedom it provides, making reductions sometimes wait unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, but that freedom comes when the reduce function is both associative and commutative.

Comment: You are absolutely right. So I confused these terms once again :) So yes, then my solution requires commutativity, and yours does not.

Answer (score 0):

Another, simple implementation can be something like:

```
let mapReduce' (map    : 'T1 -> Async<'T2>)
              (reduce : 'T2 -> 'T2 -> Async<'T2>)
              (input  : seq<'T1>) : Async<'T2> = 
        async {
            let! r = input |> Seq.map map |> Async.Parallel
            return r |> Array.toSeq 
                   |> Seq.reduce (fun a b -> reduce a b |> Async.RunSynchronously)

        }
```

In this the map phase is executed in Parallel and then reduce phase is sequential as it has data dependency on the previous calculated value.

Comment: As you point out, reduce here can't be interleaved or reordered, so it's not the same.